# Automorphisms group of complex and real simple Lie algebras

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, automorphism-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Inn}{\operatorname{Inn}}\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{\operatorname{Aut}}\DeclareMathOperator{\Out}{\operatorname{Out}}\DeclareMathOperator{\g}{\mathfrak{g}}$According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_automorphism_group#In_complex_and_real_simple_Lie_algebras), outer automorphisms as symmetries of a Dynkin diagram follows from the general fact, that for a complex or real simple Lie algebra $\g$, the automorphism group
$\Aut(\g)$ is a semidirect product of
$$\Inn(\g) \rtimes \Out(\g)$$

i.e., the short exact sequence splits:

$${{1 ⟶ \Inn(\g) ⟶ \Aut(\g) ⟶ \Out(\g) ⟶ 1}}$$

- In the complex simple Lie algebras, this is a classical result (Fulton-Harris 1991).
- In the real simple Lie algebra, this fact has been **proven as recently as 2010 (?)**. Cited this Ref: http://www.heldermann.de/JLT/JLT20/JLT204/jlt20035.htm by H. Gündogan.

> **Question: Why the complex simple Lie algebras, we already know $\Aut(\g)=\Inn(\g) \rtimes \Out(\g)$, but it took a late recent work in 2010 to settle that the real simple Lie algebra also has $\Aut(\g)=\Inn(\g) \rtimes \Out(\g)$?** (Especially given the following facts that the complex and real simple Lie algebras seem not be so different?)
 
Facts:

- Complex Lie algebra is a Lie algebra over the field $F$ as a complex  $\mathbb{C}$.
- Real Lie algebra is a Lie algebra over the field $F$ as a real  $\mathbb{R}$.
- Given a complex Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$, a real Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}_0$ is said to be a  real form of $\mathfrak g$ if the complexification $$\mathfrak{g}_0 \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C} \simeq \mathfrak{g}$$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: The real case is always harder than the complex case; over the complex numbers the existence of eigenvalues is a huge help and you don't have that over the reals.

Comment: You didn't define $\mathrm{Inn}(\mathfrak{g})$. There's a possible ambiguity. It might mean $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})^0(\mathbf{R})$, the group of real points of the algebraic connected component of the identity. Or its identity component as a Lie group, which is smaller (and usually not Zariski-closed). It is the latter group that is considered in Gündogan's paper. (An amusing case is when $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{so}(4,4)$, in which case as a Lie group, $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$ has 24 connected components.)

Comment: When $K$ is a more general field of characteristic zero and $\mathfrak{g}$ has no $K$-anisotropic factor there's a reasonable substitute for $\mathrm{Inn}(\mathfrak{g})$: the subgroup $I$ of $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$ generated by exponentials of nilpotent derivations of $\mathfrak{g}$: in the real case this yields the identity component in the Lie topology (this fails in the presence of anisotropic factors: if $\mathfrak{g}$ is anisotropic this group $I$ is reduced to the identity). Then $I$ is normal in the automorphism group, but I don't know if this splits in general.